# Reporting System Unity Freezes

Tags: 11.04, unity, bug-reporting

I have Ubuntu Natty 11.04 Beta 2 installed. I did have some compiz freezes which I reported. However today I got a System Freeze...Everything was frozen...keyboards did not respond, clicking everywhere did not work and the only way was to hard reboot the system.

Scenario 1: I was playing supertuxkaart in full screen and suddenly it froze...only a hard reset was the solution. (Did not try it again though)

Scenario 2: Had unity running for nearly 4 hours, worked on documents, listening to music and then all of a sudden it froze.

This system freeze is not conventional like after you login there is no unity or it froze after 2-3 mins of login..

However **how can I report this to launchpad since I don't know what caused the freeze and also the system couldn't generate any bug reports since I did a hard reboot?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Advanced Debugging Procedures](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/FilingBugs#Advanced%20debugging%20procedure) section of the wiki to get the information needed for the bug report.

If you can get a stack trace just report the bug by hand and attach it to the bug report.

Comment: I had a look at it, my system did not generate any apport hence that method was ruled. The other one with the stack, it said I had a graphical environment and hence should be in tty. I dont know what a tty is!

Comment: Yeah getting a trace is kind of advanced, you're probably better off updating today and see if it's still crashing.

Comment: I suppose, however your answer is correct and hence I marked it. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/757387
or this
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/758482

Is it similar to your problem? sign those bug affects you

Comment: I am sorry but they are not similar to what I am experiencing..In the sense that I might be using unity for the past 2 or 3 hours and then all of a sudden sometimes it freezes.